# How to show a custom error page in different portals like the admin section or the members section with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have routes setup for the admin section and the members section using the group prefix. How can I show different error pages for each section?

Comment: just access the first Route segment in error handler

Answer (score 0):

For example, in your **admin controller** (into a function):

```
if (isset(`whatever you want`)) {
    return redirect('/admin/error');
}
```

And in your **`routes.php`** :

```
Route::get('/admin/error', 'AdminController@showError');
```